# Android: Remove hard coding of database path

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my application in SQLite data base helper class the code of constructor is as follows:

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {    
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null ,DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    DB_PATH =  "/data/data/myPackage/databases/";
}
```

Where i am getting warning as:

**Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead**

So i tried:

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

But then too i am getting the same warning. What should i do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one thing. As do not hard core it. Try this as:

```
DB_PATH =  myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
```

This will remove your warnings.

Answer (score 3):

One Other Way to use is.

```
File datbasefile=myContext.getDatabasePath("your database name");
String name = datbasefile.getPath() ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to give a path to your db.
Let Android decide where it wants to put it.
You just need to provide the db name:

```
private final static String DB_NAME = "your_db_name.db";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "/databases/";

DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + context.getPackageName() + DATABASE_NAME;
```